# AWS Resource confusion on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to develop a Spring Cloud microservices using Spring MVC and Spring boot. And I would like to deploy in AWS cloud. When I exploring the AWS I found the computing service EC2 and Storage services EBS and Elastic Beanstalk. I found that when creating EC2 getting a default EBS volume.

- Here my doubt is that when I deploying my Spring Cloud microservice in Tomcat environment. I also need to create a RDS instance for my microservice, can I choose S3 as storage?
- And also I need to deploy my Angular 2 application using S3 and static web site hosting method. So can I use separate buckets for both microservices and Angular application hosting?

I am new to AWS and cloud service platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On S3 you can save files; its more like extensible storage as a sevice.
RDS is like RDBMS as a service..

Surely you can use separate buckets ; or different folders in same buckets.

Comment: thanks for marking my answer as correct answer. Let me know if u have more doubts